# Migrate a SharePoint Site to a SharePoint Teams Site

Tags: site, team-sites, microsoft-teams

I have a SharePoint Site called "Sales" and the Sales department created a Team which automatically created another SharePoint Site. How do I effectively migrate the original SharePoint Site to the Team SharePoint Site?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

there is no OOTB method available which will let you migrate a site to others. But still, you have a couple of options.

1. Use any 3rd party tools which let you migrate the content along with metadata from one site to other. i.e. metaglogix, sharegate etc
2. Another option is, You can manually move the content from one site to team. Like open the library with explorer then drag and drop to teams site.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what "Waqas" has advised, you can add a tab to show files from document libraries in old site collection in team site. It may help during the time migration is going on or even later, if you are ok with keeping both sites up.

[Team FAQs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Frequently-asked-questions-about-Microsoft-Teams-%E2%80%93-Admin-Help-05cbe533-2181-4e95-a4b0-52cd7695fafc)

[Add a tab to MS Team](http://windowsitpro.com/office-365/quick-tip-how-add-tab-microsoft-teams#slide-0-field_images-183481)